# Creating a round step pyramid using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, loop, looping

Creating a round step pyramid using **geometry nodes**

I know we can create a round step pyramid using the following steps but I would like to make it more procedural in geometry nodes.

[image: img]

[image: img2]

I was thinking of stacking round cylinders on top of each other with different diameters and merging each one but that seems a bit messy with the more steps I use.  Any other thoughts?  (To dream of real loops being added to geometry nodes.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this version you can control the height of the pyramid, I am using a curve line with a resample node, and I instantiate a circle at each point of the curve except the last one so that the height is exact. I also use a realize node before extruding each instance of the circle to override the scale attribute so that each step has the same scale.

[image]

*(Blender 3.2 +)*

[image: Pyramid Height]

[image: Pyramid GeoNodes Screenshoot]

Answer (score 8):

Here is a *Geometry Nodes* based replica of the *Step Pyramid*:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Don't be confused by the number of nodes, the whole thing is really just a logic game with math nodes and not really an elaborate setup.

The advantage of this solution is, however, that you create a solid mesh here, and the functionality or the result is exactly the same as with the prototype.

I've wrapped the whole thing up in a nice node group for you, so it's even easier to use:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: *"Don't be confused by the number of nodes"* – Well if you used $n$ nodes, a normal person would use $2n$…

Answer (score 4):

This one is just a late remark, really..

Another way of making a step-profile is to start with a suitably subdivided line on the diagonal of an XY unit square.

[image]

On all the odd-indexed vertices, copy the X from the vertex below, and Y from the vertex above. For a pyramid, the resulting step-profile can be swept round a curve-circle.

[image]

Scaling in XY for radius, and Z for height, can be done at the end.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

what about this node setup?

[image]

just a mesh line with cylinder instances.

[image]

or with more fill segments, then it looks more like yours:

[image]